# adjust Header Search Paths for ASIWebPageRequest

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm am just reading up on how to set up ASIWebPageRequest, and its says that you have to update your header search paths..

This is what it says to add

```
${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2
```

I have never added anything like this before I was just wondering where it should go in my code?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding this inside ..

**Targets > Build settings > Search Paths > Header Search Paths**